# How can I delete a table row by clicking a HTML button beside the row, using python flask

Tags: python, database, html, sqlite, html-table

I'm new to coding and have to do this for a school assignment. I do not have very good knowledge of code but I have to create a to-do list webpage that uses a database (SQLite3) to store the to-dos and users. I have the to-do list page successfully showing the created to-dos but I want a button beside the to-dos pulled from the database (to-dos are in table format) that will delete the table row that it is next to. I am not using django or anything like that, so is there a way that this can be done without any python extensions?
Here's my python flask code for my to-do list page

```
@app.route('/todo', methods=['GET','POST'])
def todo():
error = None
if 'login' in session:
    user = session['userid']
    db = connect_db()
    cursor = db.execute("SELECT * from todolist where userid=?",(user,))
    userdetails = cursor.fetchall()
    db.commit()
    db.close()

    if request.method == 'POST':
        userid = session['userid']
        db = connect_db()
        cursor = db.execute("DELETE FROM todolist where userid=?",(userid,))
        userdetails = cursor.fetchall()
        db.commit()
        db.close()

    return render_template('todo.html',userdetails=userdetails)


else:
    flash('Please login')
    return redirect(url_for('.login'))


else:
    flash('Please login')
    return redirect(url_for('.login'))
```

And here's my to-do html code for the table section, the rest contains bootstrap links and whatnot:

```
<h1>Your to-do list!</h1>
<p>{{message}}</p>
<body>
    <table border=1 style="width:100%">
{% for row in userdetails %}
<tr id='todorow'>
    <td>
        <form action="">
            <input type="checkbox" name="complete" value="Complete">
        </form>
    </td>
    <td>
        {{row[2]}}
    </td>
    <td>
        {{row[3]}}
    </td>
    <td><form action="/todo" method='POST'>
        <input type=submit name="delete" value="Delete"></input>
    </form></td>
    <td><form action="/todoedit">
        <input type="submit" value="Edit item"
        onclick="window.location='/todoedit';" /></input>
    </form></td>
</tr>


{%endfor%}
```

If anyone could please explain to me how I can use a html submit button to delete the to-do on the same row as the button, deleting the to-do data from the todolist database table, or what I am doing wrong in my code, and please, if you don't mind, explaining how your code works to do this.

Comment: right now, the code that handles `POST` is dead code - it comes after a `return` statement that always gets executed.

Comment: @domoarrigato thanks for letting me know. I moved the return statement to after the if statement, so there is now only one return statement for the todo, which is inline with the if request.method == 'POST':. The todo.html page is still being loaded but now when I click the delete button i get a 400 bad request error.

Comment: you need to point the form `action` at the right url. in this case `/todo` or `todo` or something

Comment: @domoarrigato I set action to '/todo' which is the url for my todo page but it is still returning a 400 bad request. Not sure what is wrong.

Comment: what does the stacktrace say?

Comment: @domoarrigato sorry I don't know what stacktrace is. I'm not very experienced with programming

Comment: its the error, as it appears in the console/shell - not in the browser.  whereever you are typing `python app.py runserver` or whatever

Comment: @domoarrigato do you mean like the error log? I have to use pythonanywhere, which has an error log if that's what you are talking about.

Comment: yes - the error log

Comment: @domoarrigato the pythonanywhere error log doesn't appear to show anything to do with 400 bad request errors. It is only showing an error from before I made the adjustments that you advised. It is showing this:   File "/home/16symonh/mysite/flask_app.py", line 188
    return render_template('todo.html',userdetails=userdetails)
                                                              ^
SyntaxError: 'return' outside function
That is no longer on that line, so the error is out of date.

Comment: @domoarrigato I have made progress by changing the todoid form to session['userid'] and removing the * from the DELETE which now works but deletes all of the data rather than just the row the delete button is on. How do I make it only delete the row of the button?

Comment: please update your post to reflect the current code

Comment: @domoarrigato I apologise, I should have done that earlier.

Comment: please fix the indentation in your code - it's not runnable in this state due to formatting errors - for example I see what might be accidentally duplicated code, or might be actual (though probably incorrect) code since there are two `else` statements at the bottom.

Comment: @domoarrigato My issue has been fixed now, I have discussed it with my teacher, who explained what I needed to do. Thanks for all your help.